# Converting char[] to uint8_t in C

Tags: c

Is there a way to **directly** convert a string to a uint8_t number?

For example: "10" to "0x10" or "D4" to "0xD4".

I've tried `uint8_t mynumber = (uint8_t)atoi(mystring);`but it always convert my string into a int first ("10" is converted to "0x0A").

Comment: You might want to read about [`strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul), where you can set the *base*.

Comment: Yeah, I think I found a way to do that! Thank you so much.